# Docker build always got '/bin/sh: 1: go: Permission denied' on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, docker-build

I am building my Docker image of miniflux below is the **Dockerfile**

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE_ARCH="amd64"

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE_ARCH}/golang:buster AS build

# blocking github workaround
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -y -qq build-essential devscripts dh-make dh-systemd && \
    mkdir -p /build/debian

ADD . /src

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/src/packaging/debian/build.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/src/packaging/debian/miniflux.postinst"]

CMD ["/src/packaging/debian/build.sh"]
```

Here is the content in /src/packaging/debian/build.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

PKG_ARCH=`dpkg --print-architecture`
PKG_DATE=`date -R`
PKG_VERSION=`cd /src && git describe --tags --abbrev=0`

echo "PKG_VERSION=$PKG_VERSION"
echo "PKG_ARCH=$PKG_ARCH"
echo "PKG_DATE=$PKG_DATE"

cd /src && \
    make miniflux && \
    mkdir -p /build/debian && \
    cd /build && \
    cp /src/miniflux /build/ && \
    cp /src/miniflux.1 /build/ && \
    cp /src/LICENSE /build/ && \
    cp /src/packaging/miniflux.conf /build/ && \
    cp /src/packaging/systemd/miniflux.service /build/debian/ && \
    cp /src/packaging/debian/compat /build/debian/compat && \
    cp /src/packaging/debian/copyright /build/debian/copyright && \
    cp /src/packaging/debian/miniflux.manpages /build/debian/miniflux.manpages && \
    cp /src/packaging/debian/miniflux.postinst /build/debian/miniflux.postinst && \
    cp /src/packaging/debian/rules /build/debian/rules && \
    echo "miniflux ($PKG_VERSION) experimental; urgency=low" > /build/debian/changelog && \
    echo "  * Miniflux version $PKG_VERSION" >> /build/debian/changelog && \
    echo " -- Frédéric Guillot <f@miniflux.net>  $PKG_DATE" >> /build/debian/changelog && \
    sed "s/__PKG_ARCH__/${PKG_ARCH}/g" /src/packaging/debian/control > /build/debian/control && \
    dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b && \
    lintian --check --color always ../*.deb && \
    cp ../*.deb /pkg/
```

Here is **Makefile** content and output of
**sudo make debian**

**Makefile:**

```
APP          := miniflux
DOCKER_IMAGE := miniflux/miniflux
VERSION      := $(shell git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
COMMIT       := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
BUILD_DATE   := `date +%FT%T%z`
LD_FLAGS     := "-s -w -X 'miniflux.app/version.Version=$(VERSION)' -X 'miniflux.app/version.Commit=$(COMMIT)' -X 'miniflux.app/version.BuildDate=$(BUILD_DATE)'"
PKG_LIST     := $(shell go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
DB_URL       := postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/miniflux_test?sslmode=disable
DEB_IMG_ARCH := amd64

export PGPASSWORD := postgres

.PHONY: \
    miniflux \
    linux-amd64 \
    linux-arm64 \
    linux-armv7 \
    linux-armv6 \
    linux-armv5 \
    linux-x86 \
    darwin-amd64 \
    darwin-arm64 \
    freebsd-amd64 \
    freebsd-x86 \
    openbsd-amd64 \
    openbsd-x86 \
    netbsd-x86 \
    netbsd-amd64 \
    windows-amd64 \
    windows-x86 \
    build \
    run \
    clean \
    test \
    lint \
    integration-test \
    clean-integration-test \
    docker-image \
    docker-image-distroless \
    docker-images \
    rpm \
    debian \
    debian-packages

miniflux:
    @ go build -buildmode=pie -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP) main.go

linux-amd64:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-amd64 main.go

linux-arm64:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-arm64 main.go

linux-armv7:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-armv7 main.go

linux-armv6:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=6 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-armv6 main.go

linux-armv5:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-armv5 main.go

darwin-amd64:
    @ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-darwin-amd64 main.go

darwin-arm64:
    @ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-darwin-arm64 main.go

freebsd-amd64:
    @ GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-freebsd-amd64 main.go

openbsd-amd64:
    @ GOOS=openbsd GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-openbsd-amd64 main.go

windows-amd64:
    @ GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-windows-amd64 main.go

build: linux-amd64 linux-arm64 linux-armv7 linux-armv6 linux-armv5 darwin-amd64 darwin-arm64 freebsd-amd64 openbsd-amd64 windows-amd64

# NOTE: unsupported targets
netbsd-amd64:
    @ GOOS=netbsd GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-netbsd-amd64 main.go

linux-x86:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-x86 main.go

freebsd-x86:
    @ GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-freebsd-x86 main.go

netbsd-x86:
    @ GOOS=netbsd GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-netbsd-x86 main.go

openbsd-x86:
    @ GOOS=openbsd GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-freebsd-x86 main.go

windows-x86:
    @ GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-windows-x86 main.go

run:
    @ LOG_DATE_TIME=1 go run main.go -debug

clean:
    @ rm -f $(APP)-* $(APP) $(APP)*.rpm $(APP)*.deb

test:
    go test -cover -race -count=1 ./...

lint:
    golint -set_exit_status ${PKG_LIST}

integration-test:
    psql -U postgres -c 'drop database if exists miniflux_test;'
    psql -U postgres -c 'create database miniflux_test;'
    go build -o miniflux-test main.go

    DATABASE_URL=$(DB_URL) \
    ADMIN_USERNAME=admin \
    ADMIN_PASSWORD=test123 \
    CREATE_ADMIN=1 \
    RUN_MIGRATIONS=1 \
    DEBUG=1 \
    ./miniflux-test >/tmp/miniflux.log 2>&1 & echo "$$!" > "/tmp/miniflux.pid"
    
    while ! nc -z localhost 8080; do sleep 1; done
    go test -v -tags=integration -count=1 miniflux.app/tests

clean-integration-test:
    @ kill -9 `cat /tmp/miniflux.pid`
    @ rm -f /tmp/miniflux.pid /tmp/miniflux.log
    @ rm miniflux-test
    @ psql -U postgres -c 'drop database if exists miniflux_test;'

docker-image:
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(VERSION) -f packaging/docker/alpine/Dockerfile .

docker-image-distroless:
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(VERSION) -f packaging/docker/distroless/Dockerfile .

docker-images:
    docker buildx build \
        --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm/v6 \
        --file packaging/docker/alpine/Dockerfile \
        --tag $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(VERSION) \
        --push .

rpm: clean
    @ docker build \
        -t miniflux-rpm-builder \
        -f packaging/rpm/Dockerfile \
        .
    @ docker run --rm \
        -v ${PWD}:/root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64 miniflux-rpm-builder \
        rpmbuild -bb --define "_miniflux_version $(VERSION)" /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/miniflux.spec

debian:
    @ docker build \
        --build-arg BASE_IMAGE_ARCH=$(DEB_IMG_ARCH) \
        -t $(DEB_IMG_ARCH)/miniflux-deb-builder \
        -f packaging/debian/Dockerfile \
        --network=host \
        .
    @ docker run --rm \
        -v ${PWD}:/pkg $(DEB_IMG_ARCH)/miniflux-deb-builder

debian-packages: clean
    $(MAKE) debian DEB_IMG_ARCH=amd64
    $(MAKE) debian DEB_IMG_ARCH=arm64v8
    $(MAKE) debian DEB_IMG_ARCH=arm32v7
```

**output of sudo make debian** , **it hang here for super long time , no response at at all** (with VPN connected), then I disconnect VPN , build continues , but still has error (posted below)

```
sudo make debian
/bin/sh: 1: go: Permission denied
Sending build context to Docker daemon  34.76MB
Step 1/10 : ARG BASE_IMAGE_ARCH="amd64"
Step 2/10 : FROM ${BASE_IMAGE_ARCH}/golang:buster AS build
 ---> addc000ec7ea
Step 3/10 : ENV GO111MODULE=on
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 37bb9dc66b5b
Step 4/10 : ENV GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de4310f89a71
Step 5/10 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66d006169476
Step 6/10 : RUN apt-get update -q &&     apt-get install -y -qq build-essential devscripts dh-make dh-systemd &&     mkdir -p /build/debian
 ---> Running in 1d212e6d1e38
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [328 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7911 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [8788 B]
Fetched 8486 kB in 1min 9s (124 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

Error messages from 'make debian':

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build'
   dh_systemd_start
   dh_perl
   dh_link
   dh_strip_nondeterminism
   dh_compress
   dh_fixperms
   dh_missing
   dh_strip
   dh_makeshlibs
   dh_shlibdeps
   dh_installdeb
   dh_gencontrol

   dh_md5sums
   dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package 'miniflux' in '../miniflux_2.0.36_amd64.deb'.
 dpkg-genbuildinfo --build=binary
 dpkg-genchanges --build=binary >../miniflux_2.0.36_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: info: binary-only upload (no source code included)
 dpkg-source --after-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: binary-only upload (no source included)
warning: the authors of lintian do not recommend running it with root privileges!
cp: cannot create regular file '/pkg/': Not a directory
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'debian' failed
make: *** [debian] Error 1
```

How can I grant my Docker container for the right permission to run my shell script ?

Comment: Looking at that error message, the `go: Permission denied` error is showing up _before_ your `docker build` command; is something in the `Makefile` trying to run a Go compile step?  It also seems like there's some sort of networking error during the `docker build` sequence but that's probably not a programming-related problem.

Comment: Please post contents of your Makefile. Looks like target docker-image depens on go binary somehow.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated my Makefile

Comment: @blami I have updated my Makefile

Comment: I think the `go` permission error is coming from setting the `$(PKG_LIST)` variable, but you're not using its value here, so that error is harmless.  Your real issue sounds like the VPN connectivity, which, again, isn't really a programming-related problem.

Comment: I think the real problem is on line `cp ../*.deb /pkg/`. Try to create a `/pkg/` directory first: `mkdir -p /pkg/ && cp ../*.deb /pkg/`